# How to reinstall Ubuntu on dual-boot macbook

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, refind

I have been trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and keep getting "could not calculate upgrade" error. I've decided that I'll just do a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and be done with it. I just want to make sure that there's nothing special I need to do, as I'm running a dual boot macbook with Ubuntu and Mac Os x using Refind. I've found step by step instructions to reinstall ubuntu on a dual boot computer by creating a live usb, but I want to make sure that it won't mess up anything. Can I just reinstall it on the same partition that I currently have ubuntu and be good? Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it should install fine, make sure to backup any files you want in your /home/user_name directory and any changes you made to files in the /etc directory to configure any apps, if not done then nothing need to be saved there. Make sure to have it format the partition to make certain there is no left overs from the previous install. Being careful of course to choose the Linux partition, no sense clobbering the Mac and now I think about it a `TM` backup would be in order in case the worst happens to it.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Ubuntu Desktop (you didn't specify), you can use the "Something-else" to select your existing partition(s) and if you don't format (a checkbox exists to select format or not for each partition), it'll cause a *upgrade via re-install*. It will note your packages installed (additional packages), erase system directories, install new system, then attempt to add back the additional packages you had installed. It won't touch user configs/files unless you selected 'format'. I don't know what 'refind' is so I've ignored that.